# How to show a div when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So i have this html code here for my main menu:

```
    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="main-wrapper">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1 id="title">portfolio</h1>

                <h2 id="ready">ready</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="selection">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="about">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="resume">resume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="contact">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what I want to do is add some animation to my website. For instance, when i click on the link "about" I want a div to show up, which is this one:

```
    <div id="secondary-container">
        <div id="about-wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="about-heading">about</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="information">
                <h2 id="introduction">introduction:</h2>
                <p id="paragraph">hello! welcome to my website!</p>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <h2 id="my-information">my information:</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>name: <span>danny moon</span></li>
                    <li>age: <span>21</span></li>
                    <li>sex: <span>male</span></li>
                    <li>location: <span>new jersey</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="feature">
                <h2 id="my-skills">my skills: </h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>html: <span>50%</span></li>
                    <li>css: <span>50%</span></li>
                    <li>javascript: <span>30%</span></li>
                    <li>python: <span>60%</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My jquery code right now is very simple

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about').click(function(){
        $('#secondary-container').show();
   });
});
```

However, when i press the "about" link, nothing happens. Any suggestions? If you guys need my full html/css/jquery/js folders

Here is a link using dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c8abu7mptjz2dkk/AABZWS-dPY7csAxIRgewP6H2a?dl=0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if you already found this, but in the files that you linked you have some minor syntax errors.

You are missing the closing brackets '>' at the end of the script tags. It should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/showhide.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have the dummy `href="#"`, when you click your link, it is probably still acting like a link - adding the "#" anchor to your URL. You should prevent the default action of a link using `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#secondary-container').show();
    });
});
```

Note the `event` param passed to your click event function.

Comment: a hash change will not reload a page

Comment: Yeah I've tried that few minutes ago.. but still nothing happen

Comment: Right. I've also learned that the hastag does not reload the page. However the url does add '#' at the end

Comment: Your solution won't work. defining e.preventDefault() would not let the click event complete. Basically making it a useless iink.

Comment: I edited my answer about the hash reloading the page. But I don't think the About link is supposed to be a real link - it is just supposed to unhide the div.